# How to set Error page in webconfig for mvc web based system

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have MVC 4 web based system. I need to handle error page in web.config file. I m try do with httpError syntax. When 404 it will show blank page. not show the actual error page. url also not show as error page.

web.config code:

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
            <remove statusCode="404" />
            <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="~/Error/PageNotFound.htm" />
    </httpErrors>
```

please help this.

Answer (score 1):

Try looking at this page: [Error Handling and Nice Error pages.](http://tech.trailmax.info/2013/08/error-handling-in-mvc-and-nice-error-pages/)

It says to add the following in the Web.Config:

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/Content/Errors/page500.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/Content/Errors/page404.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

I haven't got my MVC code infront of me but I think this is what I did.